# Find radius of convergence of $\sum (n^2 \sin(2/n^2))^{n^2+2} x^{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find the radius of convergence of $$\sum (n^2 \sin(2/n^2))^{n^2+2} x^{n^2}$$

I am not really familiar with these types of tasks, but we have two formulas:

$$R=\frac1{\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} $$

$$R=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right |$$

Do I have to plug in $a_n$ in one those and find limit, here limit is little bit tricky, and we have $x^{n^2}$, does that change anything?

Comment: The radius of convergence is $R=\frac12$ because $n^2\sin(2/n^2)\to2$.

Comment: Okay, so you used first formula, what happened with exponent $n^2+2$, can you detail your comment in answer please?

Answer (score 2):

> ... we have $x^{n^2}$, does that change anything?

Not really.

**Hint**. We may consider, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{\left|n^2 \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right|^{n^2+2} |x|^{n^2}}=\left|n^2 \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right|^{n+\frac2n} |x|^{n}
$$ and as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|n^2 \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right|^{n+\frac2n} |x|^{n}=e^{\left(n+\frac2n\right)\log\left(n^2 \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right)}|x|^{n}=e^{n\log\left(2\right)+O(1/n)} |x|^{n}\sim |2x|^n
$$ giving that *the radius of convergence is equal to* $\dfrac12$.

Comment: Sorry, but $|a_n|$ doesn't have $|x|$ in it, because formula is for series $\sum a_n x^n$

Comment: 'My' $a_n$ does ;), let's say it is $u_n(x)=a_n \cdot x^n$ and we consider $\sqrt[n]{|u_n(x)|}$ .

Comment: And i can't use O(1/n), we haven't learned that

Comment: @RushO'Brien If you're unfamiliar with asymptotic analysis, then simply note that $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$.  Then, $$\left| n^2\sin^2(2/n) \right|^{n+2/n}\le 2^{n+2/n}\le 2^n \frac{1}{1-\frac{2\log(2)}{n} }$$

Comment: @Dr.MV ...Which can only give a lower bound of the radius of convergence, not its value.

Comment: @Did And we can use $|x\cos(x)|\le |\sin(x)|$ for $|x|\le \pi/2$.  And $e^x\ge 1+x$ for the other side.  Then apply the "squeeze" theorem.

Comment: @Dr.MV I am always slightly surprised by the ingeniosity displayed on many pages of this site to *avoid* using the right tools, here the simple equivalent $\sin x\sim x$ when $x\to0$, which seems to render moot all these clever estimates... For example, I never noticed that $x\cos x\leqslant\sin x$ on $(0,\pi/2)$, of course I can check this inequality is true once it appears in your comment, but I am not convinced I should remember it... :-)

Comment: @did I agree with you.  But the OP seemed to be unaware of equivalence arguments.  The OP might be aware of simple bounds from geometry along with the squeeze theorem.  Anyway, I was only giving a way that circumvents using expansions.

Comment: If one is wondering, the inequality $2^\dfrac2n\le\dfrac1{1-\frac2n\ln(2)}$ comes from the famous inequality $1+\alpha\le e^\alpha$ for $\alpha=-\dfrac2n\ln(n)$